# Hyperledger Fabric- Chaincode not found error

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

I am having below error while installing chaincode.

> Error: Error getting chaincode code chaincode: : failed
>   with error: "exec: not started".

I am installing chaincode using below command

```
"peer chaincode install -n mycc -v 1.0 -p examples/chaincode/go/chaincode_example02.go "
```

Answer (score 0):

Try installing it with this command:

```
peer chaincode install -n mycc -v 1.0 -p examples/chaincode/go/
```

You dont have to specify the name of the file.